# Changing the value of a nested dictionary changes other nested dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, pycord

I started making a Python Discord bot in the library of Pycord. I wanted to make a bot that will work on multiple servers and each server will have different values. So, to do this I made a dictionary that will store all these values within a nested dictionary. However, when I tried to change the value of one nested dictionary, it changes the values in the other nested dictionaries.

### Code:

```
server_ids = {}
default_server_vals = {'beetle_game_started': False, 'beetle_message_id': None,
'beetle_message_channel': None, 'beetle_player_1': None, 'beetle_player_2': None, 'beetle_game_on': False, 'player1_list' : [], "player2_list":[]}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in')
    for i in bot.guilds:
        global server_ids
        global default_server_vals
        server_ids[str(i.id)] = default_server_vals
    print(server_ids)  # Generate server IDS
@bot.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    server_ids[str(guild.id)] = default_server_vals

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=testing_servers, name="beetle", description="2 Player game")
async def beetle(ctx):
    print(server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)].get('beetle_game_on'), server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)].get('beetle_game_started'))

    if server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)].get('beetle_game_on') == False and server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)].get('beetle_game_started') == False:
        await ctx.respond("Game starting! React to join.")
        game_start_embed = discord.Embed(title="React to join beetle game! (2 Players Only)",
                                         colour=discord.Colour.green())
        game_start_embed.add_field(name="GAME RULES", value="""There are two players. There is one dice! The first player to finish the beetle drawing wins.
    Rolling a 1 – Body

    Rolling a 2 – Head

    Rolling a 3 – A leg

    Rolling a 4 – An eye

    Rolling a 5 – An antenna

    Rolling a 6 – The tail
    The first player to roll all 6 wins. However, the head and body must be drawn first to draw the other beetle parts.""")
        message = await ctx.send(embed=game_start_embed)
        await message.add_reaction("")
        print(ctx.guild.id)
        server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)]['beetle_game_started'] = True
        print(server_ids)
        server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)]['beetle_message_id'] = message.id
        server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)]['beetle_message_channel'] = message.channel
    elif server_ids[str(ctx.guild.id)].get('beetle_game_started'):
        await ctx.respond("Someone already started a game! Try and join them.")
    else:
        await ctx.respond("There is already a beetle game playing!")
```

*on_ready* takes the server IDS that the bot is already in, and put it in a global *server_ids* variable. Then the nested dictionary is given as the server ID value for the dictionary. But, when I try to edit a value of a nested dictionary (inside the beetle slash command) it changes all of the other nested values.

For example, when I try to change the nested dictionary value of *beetle_game_started* it prints this:

```
{'912361242985918464': {'beetle_game_started': True, 'beetle_message_id': None, 'beetle_message_channel': None, 'beetle_player_1': None, 'beetle_player_2': None, 'beetle_game_on': False, 'player1_list': [], 'player2_list': []}, '938245167880753202': {'beetle_game_started': True, 'beetle_message_id': None, 'beetle_message_channel': None, 'beetle_player_1': None, 'beetle_player_2': None, 'beetle_game_on': False, 'player1_list': [], 'player2_list': []}}
```

It somehow changes the value of both nested dictionaries of the server IDS (the value of 'beetle_game_started')
How would I change the value of one nested dictionary without changing the value of others?

Comment: Python dictionaries are mutable objects.  The issue may be in trying to assign default_server_vals to every id.  In this line, server_ids[str(guild.id)] = default_server_vals, you're not creating new dictionaries, instead, you're creating new references to one dictionary.

Comment: @somebody3697
Wait but It's a different server guild.id every time it is run. I'm a bit confused as to what you mean. It does create a new dictionary as shown in the print statement. Thanks btw.

Comment: Using the example dictionary in the print statement, call it d, check the id of the value for '912361242985918464' and compare it to the id value for '938245167880753202'.  In other words check if id(d['912361242985918464']) == id(d['938245167880753202']).  If that equivalence returns True, then your ids are pointing to the same dictionary

Comment: @somebody3697 Oh, I see! It's one dictionary reference two times! I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: YEES @somebody3697 TYSM I made the dictionary as a copy instead of a reference! It actually works now (at least I think so with some minor testing) Please add this as an answer so others can know too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see this behavior is because in Python dictionaries are mutable objects.

Pulling the relevant sections from the code provided

```
default_server_vals = {'beetle_game_started': False, 'beetle_message_id': None,
'beetle_message_channel': None, 'beetle_player_1': None, 'beetle_player_2': None, 'beetle_game_on': False, 'player1_list' : [], "player2_list":[]}
```

and

```
server_ids[str(i.id)] = default_server_vals
```

The server_ids[str(i.id)] assignment is just creating new references to a single dictionary.  This is why when you change the value for one id, you observe the change for all other ids.

One way to get around this is to make a copy.  I suggest taking a look at Python's [copy library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html).

Since *default_server_vals* contains lists as values, you'll want to consider *deepcopy*.