# How do I idenpendently modify values in a Python nested dictionary, when they share keys with other dictionaries in the nest?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I have two dictionaries similar to the following:

```
RegionData = {
    "Canada":{"Capitol":"Otowa", "Currency":"filler", "Climate":"cold"},
    "USA":{"Capitol":"DC", "Currency":"filler", "Climate":"moderate"},
    "Mexico":{"Capitol":"Mexico City", "Currency":"filler", "Climate":"cold"}
}

CurrencyData = {"Canada":"Canada Dollar", "USA":"US Dollar", "Mexico":"Peso"}
```

I'm trying to modify the nested dictionary such that the values in CurrencyData modify the currency values in RegionData.

I've tried many iterations of the following:

```
for value in RegionData.keys():
    if value in CurrencyData:
        RegionData[value]["Currency"] = CurrencyData[value]
```

However, I always end up with the same thing:

```
 RegionData = {
    "Canada":{"Capitol":"Otowa", "Currency":"Peso", "Climate":"cold"}, 
    "USA":{"Capitol":"DC", "Currency":"Peso", "Climate":"moderate"},        
    "Mexico":{"Capitol":"Mexico City", "Currency":"Peso", "Climate":"cold"}
}
```

What I want is:

```
RegionData = {
    "Canada":{"Capitol":"Otowa", "Currency":"Canada Dollar", "Climate":"cold"},
    "USA":{"Capitol":"DC", "Currency":"US Dollar", "Climate":"moderate"},
    "Mexico":{"Capitol":"Mexico City", "Currency":"Peso", "Climate":"cold"}
}
```

Note: I'm using python3.9 if that matters. Also this questions seems similar: [Changing the value of a nested dictionary changes other nested dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190560/changing-the-value-of-a-nested-dictionary-changes-other-nested-dictionary-values) but I am not able to follow the conversation, so I wanted to simplify so I can understand how to fix it, and why it happens.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: My original thought was that the nested dictionaries are references to the same dictionary. But then they would also have the same `Capitol` and `Climate`.

Comment: I just tried your code, and it worked for me also. Looks like it runs the way you intended for it to run.

Comment: Thanks for responses. I tried this on my IDE and it works. However, when I do this in my lambda function it doesn't. In my actual code I'm using dictionary comprehension to create the dictionaries, I think Barmar has the right idea. I've probably done something in how I create these dictionaries to make them references to each other.